# What would be the diet on the Lord of the Flies's island?

Tags: lord-of-the-flies, william-golding

If there were an uninhabited tropical island (assumed to be in the Pacific) with the conditions and history necessary for pigs, and pink granite, what would the boys likely have eaten?

It's mentioned that they predominately eat fruit and nuts, with the occasional fish or crab. Later, they start eating pork.

But what kinds of edible flora would there likely be, are there almost definitely other animals there, and could they have a balanced diet?